# Assign to one object cause change also in another object

Tags: vba, ms-word

Following this code, I got a strange behavior. assigning to one range object cause change also in another object

```
Sub test()
  Dim pRange1 As Word.Range
  Dim pRange2 As Word.Range
  ' ActiveDocument.Range => String "12"
  Set pRange1 = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(1) 'pRange1 =1
  '
  Set pRange2 = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(2) 'pRange1 =2
 
 pRange1.Text = "3" ' pRange1=3 and pRange2=33 ????!!!
   
End Sub
```

Why after assignment of

```
pRange1.Text = "3"
```

pRange1 object also changed?

Comment: Can't replicate the behaviour you're describing on my side

Comment: I can’t replicate it either. Something else must be going on. You do know that the code you shared is only looking at the 1st and 2nd characters in the document, right? Is that your intent? Also, I think you have a typo in your question ... are you seeing pRange2 change after altering pRange1? Your question is asking why pRange1 changed and I think you mean pRange2.

Comment: Is Track Changes on?

Comment: No, the track changes is off

Answer (score 0):

I **think** this is what's happening (I am open to corrections):

The first thing to note is that `Range.Characters(1)` is the same as `Range(0, 1)` which means the range starting at character with index `0` up to *but not including* character with index `1`

It *appears to me* that setting `Range.Text = "ab"` happens in two stages. First the range is deleted (`Range.Delete`) and then the text `"ab"` is assigned to the range.

The following code should explain the behaviour:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim r3 As Range
    
    With ActiveDocument
        .Range = "abc"
    
        Set r1 = .Range(0, 1) '* similar to .Characters(1)
        Set r2 = .Range(1, 2) '* similar to .Characters(2)
        Set r3 = .Range(2, 3) '* similar to .Characters(3)
        
        '* At this point r1, r2 and r3 are distinct ranges
        
        Debug.Print "Before:"
        Debug.Print "-------"
        
        Debug.Print "r1: " & r1 & vbTab & "start index: " & r1.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r1.End
        Debug.Print "r2: " & r2 & vbTab & "start index: " & r2.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r2.End
        Debug.Print "r3: " & r3 & vbTab & "start index: " & r3.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r3.End
        
        r1.Delete
        
        '* At this point r1 is a subset of r2. Therefore, changing
        '* r1 will change r2. r3 is a distinct range
        
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "After Deletion:"
        Debug.Print "---------------"
        
        Debug.Print "r1: " & r1 & vbTab & "start index: " & r1.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r1.End
        Debug.Print "r2: " & r2 & vbTab & "start index: " & r2.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r2.End
        Debug.Print "r3: " & r3 & vbTab & "start index: " & r3.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r3.End
        
        r1.Text = "z"
        
        '* At this point r1 is still a subset of r2. r3 is a distinct range
        
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "After Adding Text:"
        Debug.Print "------------------"
        
        Debug.Print "r1: " & r1 & vbTab & "start index: " & r1.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r1.End
        Debug.Print "r2: " & r2 & vbTab & "start index: " & r2.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r2.End
        Debug.Print "r3: " & r3 & vbTab & "start index: " & r3.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r3.End
      
    End With
  
End Sub
```

The output is:

```
Before:
-------
r1: a   start index: 0  end index: 1
r2: b   start index: 1  end index: 2
r3: c   start index: 2  end index: 3

After Deletion:
---------------
r1:     start index: 0  end index: 0
r2: b   start index: 0  end index: 1
r3: c   start index: 1  end index: 2

After Adding Text:
------------------
r1: z   start index: 0  end index: 1
r2: zb  start index: 0  end index: 2
r3: c   start index: 2  end index: 3
```

**Edit:** (following comment below)

Here's a not-so-pretty workaround. The main idea is to insert the new text *and then* delete the old text. This way the *next* range `r2` doesn't collapse into the *current* range `r1` (i.e. distinct ranges remain separate).

```vb
Sub Test2()
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim r3 As Range
    
    With ActiveDocument
        .Range = "abc"
    
        Set r1 = .Characters(1)
        Set r2 = .Characters(2)
        Set r3 = .Characters(3)
        
        Debug.Print "Before:"
        Debug.Print "-------"
        Debug.Print "r1: " & r1 & vbTab & "start index: " & r1.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r1.End
        Debug.Print "r2: " & r2 & vbTab & "start index: " & r2.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r2.End
        Debug.Print "r3: " & r3 & vbTab & "start index: " & r3.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r3.End
        
        ReplaceRangeText r1, "z"
        
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print "After:"
        Debug.Print "------"
        Debug.Print "r1: " & r1 & vbTab & "start index: " & r1.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r1.End
        Debug.Print "r2: " & r2 & vbTab & "start index: " & r2.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r2.End
        Debug.Print "r3: " & r3 & vbTab & "start index: " & r3.Start & vbTab & "end index: " & r3.End
    End With
End Sub

Function ReplaceRangeText(rng As Range, sNewText As String) As Range
    Dim sOldText As String
    With rng
        sOldText = .Text
        .InsertBefore sNewText
        .Document.Range(.Start + Len(sNewText), .End).Delete
    End With
    Set ReplaceRangeText = rng
End Function
```

The output is:

```
Before:
-------
r1: a   start index: 0  end index: 1
r2: b   start index: 1  end index: 2
r3: c   start index: 2  end index: 3

After:
------
r1: z   start index: 0  end index: 1
r2: b   start index: 1  end index: 2
r3: c   start index: 2  end index: 3
```

Comment: so... How should I only replace character value?

Comment: I fund that this line also solve the issue (I think):  pRange1.Characters(1).Text = "3"

Comment: Interesting, that doesn't work for me: I end up with `pRange1=""` and `pRange2="32"`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I cannot think of any practical reason why you would need to keep the ranges distinct? Is this just an intellectual exercise?

Comment: I need to scan a large document (loop on every character) and sometimes modify it according to logical condition

Comment: Ok, in that case you simply loop through all characters (preferably backward) and modify appropriately. If you cannot get it to work, post another question with your code and hopefully someone will be able to help you. I still don't see how the above will cause any issues for you.